# How to call a javascript function and alter a variable in an Angular controller?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to learn angular.js. I am just trying to understand the basic concepts. I have taken an example from W3Schools and tried to alter it to display a variable that can be incremented by the click of a button. I'm trying to keep the different elements as separate as possible so I can understand how everything connects. I have left a portion of the example in just be be sure enerything is working as it is suppose to. Here is my code that doesn't work.

LearningAngular.js

```
    var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
    myApp.controller("myController", myController);

    function myController($scope) {
        $scope.firstName = "John";
        $scope.counter = 0;    
    }

function start_counting(){
     myController.counter ++;
}
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Learning Angular</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="LearningAngular.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">

    First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
    <br>
    Full Name: {{firstName}}<br>

    <button onclick="start_counting()">Start Counting</button><br>
    Counter: <span>{{counter}}</span>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The function should be declared in the $scope's scope:

```
function myController($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.counter = 0;    
    $scope.start_counting = function(){
           $scope.counter ++;
     };
   $interval(function() {
       $scope.start_counting();
   }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I will give that a try]

Comment: That work thanks. Next question is how would I make that work with say setInterval so it increments the variable automatically.

Comment: @PerLarsen - Added interval example, note that you need to inject `$interval` to the controller function

Comment: you should either put that up as a different question or update your existing question.

Comment: I did as you suggested but it starts counting as soon as you hit the refresh button

Comment: You've asked me for interval example so this what I did. Please clarify your requirements

Comment: No worries I'm going to take what you showed and see if I can figure it out first. Thanks for your help. I will post a new question if I can't get it.

Comment: @PerLarsen Thanks :)

Comment: @Medet if it is the wrong solution what is the right one.

Answer (score 1):

Keep all the functions needed inside the main component function. You need to have access to $scope in order to change the view

```
  function myController($scope) {
        $scope.firstName = "John";
        $scope.counter = 0; 

      // iniitalize counter when controller is initialized
       start_counting();

        // a simple function only used in controller, not view
       function start_counting(){
          $scope.counter ++;
       }         

    }
```

If you need to use that function in the view for example in an `ng-click` then just do:

```
$scope.start_counting = start_counting;// pass function reference to $scope
```

Don't use `onclick` in the view ... use `ng-click` so you can access methods in controller scope. `onclick` only has access to global window variables and functions...not angular scoped ones

```
<button ng-click="start_counting()">Start Counting</button><br>
```

Comment: just added explanation of why